# tmutil associatedisk on macOS Sonoma - volume mount point and volume path

Tags: time-machine, sonoma

I'm trying to reassociate an external SSD drive restored from a Time Machine backup on MacOS Sonoma 14.3.

I used all kinds of combinations of this command:

```
sudo tmutil associatedisk -a "/Volumes/<My drive>" "/Volumes/MY TimeMachine Drive/YYYY-MM-DD-TTTTTT.previous/<My external drive>"
sudo tmutil associatedisk -a /Volumes/<My external drive> /Volumes/.timemachine/AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA/YYYY-MM-DD-TTTTTT.backup/YYYY-MM-DD-TTTTTT.backup/<My external drive>
```

Yet I always keep getting this message:

```
A local volume mount point and a snapshot volume path are required.
```

The `man` page uses super outdated format for the snaphost volume path. It seems this `tmutil associatedisk` function doesn't work at tall anymore or there's some "secret" new format for the format of the paths.

Please help!

Comment: Does my answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453387/time-machine-restore-to-new-external-drive help you? I believe your -a is not correct for APFS TM disk.